# Trigonometric function through predefined points

Tags: functions, trigonometry

Is there a linear combination of trigonometric functions which takes the values 1 for all multiplies of 5 and the value 0 for all other integers (6, 7, 8 etc.). The rest can take any value.

I tried hard to come up with one but couldn't succeed. Is there a proof that this isn't possible?

For example for the number 3 the function is pretty easy
$$
y = \frac{2}{3}\cos\frac{2\pi}{3}x+\frac{1}{3}.
$$

Answer (score 0):

This is not a linear combination, but it still may help.

$$
y=0.64\cos ^4(\frac{2\cdot\pi\cdot x}{5})+0.64\cos ^3(\frac{2\cdot\pi\cdot x}{5})-0.16\cos ^2(\frac{2\cdot\pi\cdot x}{5})-0.16\cos (\frac{2\cdot\pi\cdot x}{5})+0.04
$$